# Mass Email with PHP

Tags: php, email

I want to create a script that will send up to 300 emails using my web host.
I will be adding a random delay after each email so I will not be sending them all at once.
I have read in previous questions and they advised that I should not use mail() but swiftmailer, however, I think those answers are now outdated since it's now 2016.
Is swiftmailer still the way to go or can I simply use mail()?

Also, I will have the email and firstname in a text document and would like to customize the emails using variables.
Does the information from the text document need to be inserted into a database before sending out emails or can I read directly from the text document?

Comment: You can read from the text document, without a 'database'.

Comment: As a guide you can search packagist for library/package popularity.

Comment: Using PHP's `mail()` in default configurations is IMO never good if you want messages to be received properly -- there are many pitfalls with receiver's anti-spam, blocklists, etc. Using a proper mail library with a proper SMTP server is your best bet.  For the 2nd part in your question, there is no need for such databases, all depends on the best way you want to structure and manage your project.

Comment: Did you try ?? If yes then whats the problem ??